# Can dissections always be 'adjusted' to polygonal dissections?

Tags: geometry, dissection

Given two polygons, a *dissection* is a decomposition of the two polygons into a finite set of "nice" pieces with disjoint interiors, along with a bijection between the sets of pieces where a piece of A is matched to a congruent piece of B.

For example, here is Dudeney's famous dissection of an equilateral triangle into a square.

[image: Dudeney's dissection of a triangle into a square]

(One reasonable definition of "nice" is that each piece is a regular-closed set (aka equal to the closure of its interior) whose interior is connected and whose boundary is a Lebesgue null set.)

If there is a dissection between two polygons, is there a *polygonal* dissection between them with the same number of pieces? Furthermore, can we assume the polygonal dissection is arbitrarily close to the original, in some reasonable metric?

(Note - though I'm not sure why you would - that the reverse question is not true: Dudeney's dissection cannot be adjusted to a non-polygonal dissection. In fact, I think it's completely rigid - it cannot be adjusted to any other dissection at all.)

For a nontrivial example of a dissection between two polygons involving a curve, see this dissection between a Latin cross and a square using a circular arc.

[image: A dissection between a Latin cross and a square]

Comment: I'm calling a piece whose boundary is a Warsaw circle "nice" so you may gather that my standards are quite low

Comment: What is a Warsaw circle ? The approximation of the Polish boundary by a circle ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Google Images should show you several variations but it's basically [this thing](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/files/warsaw.gif) - the topologist's sine curve (graph of $\sin1/x$) made into a loop. (By "Polish boundary" do you mean the borders of Poland?)

Comment: Thanks for the precision. Yes of course, I could have used "Google images" but it's better that you give yourself a reference for such terms that are usual for only a little ... circle.